# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, by invoking fsolve

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to use fsolve from scipy.optimization to solve a set of 6 non-linear equations in the complex number space. 
Unfortuantely I always get the error:

`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

with the following code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

U_1  = 465
R_1  = 0.007255
R_21 = 0.006906607
M    = 585.3
p    = 2
f_1  = 91
omega_1 = np.pi*f_1
X_1sig = omega_1 * 2.0979e-4
X_2sig = omega_1 * 1.5016923e-4
X_m = omega_1 * 5.074 

def equations(p):
    P_el, P_m, I_1, I_2, s, n = p
    return (
    -P_el + 3*np.real(U_1*np.conjugate(I_1)),
    -P_el + 3*(I_1*np.conjugate(I_1)*R_1 + I_2**2*R_21/s),
    -P_m  + 3*I_2**2*R_21*(1-s)/s,
    -P_m  + M/(2*np.pi*n),
    -s    + 1 - p*n/f_1,
    -I_1  + U_1/(R_1 + 1j*X_1sig + 1j*X_m*(R_21/s+1j*X_2sig)/(1j*X_m + R_21/s + 1j*X_2sig))
    )

P_el, P_m, I_1, I_2, s, n = fsolve(equations, (180000,180000,200+80j,20,0.01,45))
```

I have reduced the code to a smaller example, but then the error disappears. I heard that fsolve can only solve problems in the real number space. So this might be the issue. But then wouldn't I get a different error message? I still want to use the code for different solvers (if I find any for complex numbers), so it would be good if I get rid of the problem first. 
G

Comment: Have you checked the output of `equations(x0)`? It seems that there are issues with the returned tuple.

Comment: Especially the `p` in  `-s  + 1 - p*n/f_1,` seems very suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

As cel pointed out p as the argument of equations(p) interferes with p as the global variable. 
The solution thus is:

```
def equations(x0):
   P_el, P_m, I_1, I_2, s, n = x0
```

instead of

```
def equations(p):
   P_el, P_m, I_1, I_2, s, n = p
```